# Selling properties

Tags: property

Assalamualaikum, may Allah bless our lives with full prosperity and easiness, I bear to witness that there is no God other than Allah SWT, and Prophet Muhammad SAW is His Messenger.

So basically the question is quite simple. My mother has given me so many clothes from filth market and some of the clothes that she has gotten were for free. I want to give to the people the clothes by selling them because I want to gain some profit. The prices will be just extremely cheap because these are old clothes. My question is, is it permissible in Islam to sell some stuffs that we have gained or received from other people for free? My intention is simply to get rid of so many clothes because it is overloading my wardrobe  However, Allah SWT knows the best and the only one knows His servant's true intentions. I hope this question doesn't confuses the scholars and may Allah eases the ones who can manage to answer my inquiry. Jazakallahu Khairan, assalamualaikum

Comment: Can you tell any possible reason for why this could be impermissible ?